# iPhone - play movie in detailView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, media-player, avaudioplayer

I am having a tableView which lists the contents directory which includes jpg, pdf, zip, mp3, mp4, sql,.. files and even folders. For the next step, I should have a detailView which displays some properties of the selected file such as fileName, fileSize, filePath, fileType. Everything works perfect.

But actually my plan is to include a additional option in the detailView.

That is,

1. If the selected file in the tableView is a image file, it should open a imageView in the   detailView to display that image.
2. If the selected file is a mp3, it should open a player to play the song in the detailView.
3. If the selected file is a video or mp4 file, it should open a player to play that video in detailView.
4. If the selected item is a folder, it should again open a tableView which dispalys the contents of the folder.![alt text][1]
5. For other files, it should push a alertView regarding that it is a unknown file.

Hope my concept was narrated.
Please help me to proceed with some sample codes. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check with iPhone site and core things, that may help your project.

Comment: Wow. What a great answer... :(